# Is it possible to set up programmatically constraint between keyboard and UITextView?

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextview, nslayoutconstraint

I need to reduce textview size when keyboard is visible, I do not want to overlap with keyboard. Any idea how can I get reference of keyboard, to create programmatically a `NSLayoutConstraint`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is Possible as per my View try this it is not set Constrain but you can Resize of your TextView.

in your ViewDidLoad method Write Notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

And set your textview Size when KeyBoard is Appear like as

```
- (void) keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
     self.textView.frame=CGRectMake(As Your needed size);
}
```

and if you want to make when KeyBoard dismiss then i want my TextView Size as set then you set new method like as

```
- (void) keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
self.textview.frame=cgrectmake(As your Exact Size);
}
```

and also Write a Resign First Responder method for your textview if you want it like as

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
[self.textView resignFirstResponder];  
 }
```